# How to do "not" arrows in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles

SO I thought this should be somehow possible but after going on an hour long dive about arrows and arrowstyles in tikz I have not learned of an option to draw crossed arrows with tikz. Basically I want to use just a simple `\draw [->,thick] (A.east) -- node [below]{Text} (B);` with the arrow instead of normal crossed out. Something similar to `$\not\Rightarrow$`. Do you have an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to place an additional node with a slash:

[image]

I shifted the "text" node down slightly to give the slash more space. Use `sloped` for the slash so it rotates with the line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->,thick] (0,0) -- node[sloped]{\textbf{/}}node[below=3pt]{Text} (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```